# Использована неинициализированная локальная переменная

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется код:

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int n = 3;
    int m = 3;
    int maxi;
    int maxj;
    int** Mas ;
    int** Bufer ;
    initMemory(Mas , n, m);
    initMemory(Bufer ,n, m);
    Zapoln(Mas, n, m);
    cout << "Massive: " << endl;
    vyvod(Mas, n, m);
    Masscopy(Bufer, Mas, n, m);
    cout << "Copy of massive: " << endl;
    vyvod(Bufer , n, m);
    freeMemory(Mas, n);
    initMemory(Mas, n - 1, m - 1);
    int max = maxel(Bufer, n, m, maxi, maxj);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Max element: " << "[" << maxi << "]" << "[" << maxj << "]" << "=" << max << endl;
    cout << endl;
    del(Bufer, maxi, maxj, n, m);
    vozvr(Mas, Bufer , n -1 , m -1);
    cout << "After massive: " << endl;
    vyvod(Mas, n - 1, m - 1);
    freeMemory(Bufer, n);
    delete[] Bufer;
    system("pause");
}
```

memory.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
void initMemory(int **A, int n, int m) {
    A = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = new int[m];
    }
}
void freeMemory(int **A, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete[] A[i];
    }
}
```

Array_helper.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
void vyvod(int **A, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "mas[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]=" << setprecision(3) << *(*(A + i) + j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void Zapoln(int **A, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            *(*(A + i) + j) = rand() % 26 - rand() % 26;
        }
    }
}
void Masscopy(int** A, int** B, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            *(*(A + i) + j) = *(*(B + i) + j);
        }
    }
}

void del(int **A, int  maxi, int maxj, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = maxi; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = maxj; j < m - 1; j++) {
            *(*(A + i) + j) = *(*(A + i + 1) + j + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Logic.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
void vozvr(int** A, int** B, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            *(*(A + i) + j) = *(*(B + i) + j);
        }
    }
}
int maxel(int **A, int n, int m, int& maxi, int& maxj)
{
    int Max = A[0][0];
    maxi = maxj = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j< m; j++)
            if (fabs(A[i][j]) > fabs(Max))
            {
                Max = fabs(*(*(A + i) + j));
                maxi = i;
                maxj = j;
            }
    return Max;
}
```

Однако при выполнении выдает ошибку:

- > 1>d:\загрузки\source.cpp(10): error C4700: использована
  >   неинициализированная локальная переменная "Mas"
  >   1>d:\загрузки\source.cpp(11): error C4700: использована
  >   неинициализированная локальная переменная "Bufer"

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int** Mas ;
int** Bufer ;
initMemory(Mas , n, m);
initMemory(Bufer ,n, m);
```

Что бы вы ни делали и какую память не выделяли в `initMemory` - она буде благополучно потеряна, потому что вы просто передаете копию указателя в функцию...

Если вы хотите, чтобы `Mas` и `Buf` содержали указатели на выделенную память - `initMemory` должна принимать `int***`, а передавать в нее нужно `&Mas` и `&Buf`...